# google custom search api Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to use google custom search api for java but in some reason it not works. Here is my java code:

```
 String searchText = "football";
    String key="mykey";
    String cx = "mygeneratedcx";

   HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer = new HttpRequestInitializer() {

    @Override
    public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {

    }
};
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

   Customsearch custom = new Customsearch(new NetHttpTransport(), jsonFactory,            httpRequestInitializer);
    Customsearch.Cse.List list = custom.cse().list("football");
    list.setCx(cx);
    list.setKey(key);

   Search result = list.execute();

  List listResult = (List) result.getItems();
 Result first = (Result) listResult.get(0);
```

And thease are my dependencies to use the api:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
<artifactId>google-api-client-http</artifactId>
<version>1.2.3-alpha</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
<artifactId>google-api-services-customsearch</artifactId>
<version>v1-rev30-1.17.0-rc</version>
</dependency>
```

I have seen some examples, but they are not according to thease version of api which I get.
When above code executes I received a following exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.util.Strings.isNullOrEmpty(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClient

If somebody have used this google custom search api for java, I would be very thankful for help!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved. I' ve changed dependency for google api client with this:
    
    com.google.http-client
    google-http-client-jackson
    1.15.0-rc